# Why is the time derivative of the magnetic field finite?

Tags: electromagnetism

One step in finding the interface conditions for electromagnetic waves involves recognizing that as $\vec{A}\rightarrow 0$, $\int_{\vec{A}}\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt}d\vec{A}=0$.  Specifically, we usually treat $A$ as a rectangle with one side begin driven to zero. This is justified as $\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt}$ is finite.

Of course, this does not hold generally. $\vec{B}$ could, for instance, be a delta function ($B = \delta(z)t$). It doesn't *seem* as though this is explicitly prohibited by Maxwell's equations. Do the interface conditions solely come about because, for practical purposes, we're only interested in smooth solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically $dB/dt$ is finite.

But one might be interested in a case where $dB/dt$ is large enough that it cannot be neglected on the distance scale associated with an interface, such as for example the size of atoms. This can happen with X-rays, or with other wavelengths at high enough intensity. And then indeed the 'standard' continuity results do not apply.